# What is the exact meaning of "protest"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The below is an example sentence of "protest".

> She has always protested her innocence.

What does that mean?

1. She has continued to assert that she is innocent.
2. She has continued to assert that she is guilty. (She is afraid of being drunk and hurting her child.)
3. Both are possible, according to circumstances.

Comment: Choice 2 makes me think some context is missing. Is this from a longer text? How do we know she has a child and gets drunk?

Comment: @Mixolydian It's just the possibility that it could be.

Comment: Do *she* and *her* refer to the same person? Does *innocence* refer to a moral or a legal status? What exactly is meant by the sentence may vary depending on such details. This is why we ask to be provided [complete context](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439), particularly when asking about meaning.

Comment: @choster Yes, Both "She" is the same person. It's just my imagination. A mother is beseeching to a judge to put her in prison. She is afraid of herself. Because she is an alcoholic and loses her reason when drunk and beats her children badly against her will.

Answer (score 2):

To "protest his innocence" is an idiom. It means simply "to assert that he is innocent". It would never mean "assert he is guilty".

The meaning of "protest (something)" as "affirm" used to be more common. Now it is mostly heard in fixed idiomatic expressions like "protest my innocence".

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wasn't sure about this one. I could have sworn that you always protest **against** something because you disagree with what that something implies. But looking for more information, I have found this text in the Cambridge Dictionary

**[protest](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/protest)**

> B2 - to say something forcefully or complain about something:
>
> *All through the trial **he protested his innocence** (= strongly said **he was
>   not guilty**).*

It's almost your exact sentence explained! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say choice 3 is correct. To protest one’s innocence usually means to argue *for* one’s innocence, but could mean to argue *against* one’s innocence in certain situations.

Examples of each:

> 1. I swear I didn’t commit the crime!

(that would be protesting *for* one's innocence)

> 2. I am not as naïve as you think I am!

(that would be protesting *against* one's innocence)

But as other answerers note, "to protest [one's] innocence" is an idiomatic expression meaning "arguing in favor of [one's] innocence" - that's the more likely meaning. It is counterintuitive, though, since "to protest" usually means "to argue against."